# create playlist in spotify ios application

Tags: ios, spotify

I am working on creating playlist by using spotify api.

I am able to fetch list of playlist by below code :-

```
[SPTRequest playlistsForUserInSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTListPage *list){
            if (error != nil) {
                UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Getting User Info Failed"
                                                               message:error.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [view show];
                return;
            }


            NSLog(@"list==>%@",list.items);

        }];
```

But i found that there is below function use to create playlist with name.
The class name is `SPTPlaylistList`
But i dont know how to use this below function.Please help me.

```
-(void)createPlaylistWithName:(NSString *)name publicFlag:(BOOL)isPublic session:(SPTSession *)session callback:(SPTPlaylistCreationCallback)block;
```

Answer (score 1):

`playlistsForUserInSession:` returns an `SPTPlaylistList` object, not an `SPTListPage`. Change your call to look like this and you'll be fine:

```
[SPTRequest playlistsForUserInSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTPlaylistList *list) {

    ...
}];
```

This is in the documentation supplied with the library and in the headers. In fact, if you `Alt`+Click the `playlistsForUserInSession:` method in your code, you'll get a little pop-up that'll tell you that you get an `SPTPlaylistList` back. Reading the documentation will save you a lot of time!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please my question is about creating the playlist. How do i create the playlist..